# Trazer dados da Tabela e não retorna nenhum resultado

Tags: php, tabela-html, crud

Galera estou com um problema ao fazer a busca de dados em uma tabela, segue código.

**CÓDIGO PHP**

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "vitor";
$senha = "";
$banco = "funcionarios_db";
$mysqllink = mysqli_connect("$servidor","$usuario","$senha","$banco");

<?php

$parametro = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "parametro");
if($parametro){
    $dados = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE funcionario LIKE '%$parametro%' ORDER BY id_matricula");
}
    else {
        $dados = mysqli_query($mysqllink, "SELECT * FROM funcionario ORDER BY id_matricula");

}

$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($dados); ?>
```

**TABELA**

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>ID Matrícula</td>
    <td>Funcionário</td>
    <td>Cargo</td>
    <td>Alocado</td>
</tr>
<?php
    if($total){ do{

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $linha['ID Matrícula'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['Funcionário'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['Cargo'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['Alocado'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
    } while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados));
    mysqli_free_result($dados);}

    mysqli_close($mysqllink);
?>
```

**Galera esta retornando isto da minha tabela:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Variável não escapa com aspas simples só com aspas duplas, eu acho que o erro é esse. Tente substituir
        "SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE funcionario LIKE '%$parametro%' ORDER BY id_matricula" por
         'SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE funcionario LIKE %".$parametro."% ORDER BY id_matricula'

Comment: Esta fazendo algum tipo de consulta no banco de dados com parametro GET?

Comment: Vinicius não deu certo

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus Creio que não seja esse o problema, ja que as aspas simples se referem ao parâmetro like e a variável $parametro está dentro de aspas duplas.

Comment: @JoãoLima está tendo algum erro? caso sim poderia informar qual? Abraços.

Comment: @Gustavo Luciano infelizmente não, ele somente cria a trabela com as colunas da table, e não exibe as linhas do banco

Comment: Como assim só cria a tabela? a tabela já não está criada?

Comment: @Vinicius de Jesus Fiz um EDIT no post e coloquei a imagem da tabela.

Comment: normalmente usasse um for como estrutura de repetição para se imprimir dados de uma tabela, principalmente por causa da variável que faz a iteração ser utilizada como index da array.

Comment: olha minha resposta lá em baixo e me retorna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitui seu código por este.

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "vitor";
$senha = "";
$banco = "funcionarios_db";
$mysqllink = mysqli_connect("$servidor","$usuario","$senha","$banco");


$parametro = "";
if(isset($_GET['parametro'])) {
    $parametro = $_GET['parametro'];
}
//


$sql = ("SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE funcionario LIKE '%$parametro%' ORDER BY id_matricula");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqllink, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($total > 0 ) { ?>


<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>ID Matrícula</td>
    <td>Funcionário</td>
    <td>Cargo</td>
    <td>Alocado</td>
</tr>

<?php do { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $linha['ID Matrícula'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['Funcionário'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['Cargo'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['Alocado'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>

</table>        


<?php   }

    //
    else {

        echo 'Nenhuma consulta para esta matricula.';

    }
    //
?>
```

Comment: não funcionou ainda colega, não trouxe nenhum resultado do banco de dados, somente trouxe a contagem de linhas de dados que meu banco possui, no caso 4.

Comment: tenta substituir o if($total > 0 por if($linha > 0 no seu campo input em name ="parametro" com method="GET" no seu form

Comment: fiz um edit no post, e esta me trazendo aquela imagem !

Comment: Me traz o o formulário pra eu analisar, vou fazer um teste aqui no meu servidor.

Comment: <form method="GET"> 
     <label id="txt">Pesquise por alguem:</label>
                <input id="barra" type="text" name="parametro" placeholder="Faça sua busca"/>
                <input class="botao" type="submit" value="Pesquisar"></a> 
                <input class="botao" type="submit" value="Retornar"/>
    </form>

Comment: eu tentei e deu certo, veja bem o seu banco de dados como esta sua tabela, os campos da tabela nao pode conter caracteres nem acentos e nem espaços, somente utilize as palavras sem caracteres e ao inves de espaço utilize underline por exemplo id_funcionario no seu echo da tabela esta $linha['ID Funcionario'] com espaços deve ser por isso que nao esta retornando os valores verifique por que aqui esta funcionando normalmente.

Comment: é exatamente isso, não me atentei a table! Muito obrigado colega. Abraços !

Comment: Disponha qualquer duvida da um salve!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tente usando um for, assim:

```
<?php
if($total){

    for ($i=0; $i < $total-1; $i++) { 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $linha[$i]['ID Matrícula'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linha[$i]['Funcionário'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linha[$i]['Cargo'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $linha[$i]['Alocado'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
    }
    mysqli_free_result($dados);}

    mysqli_close($mysqllink);
    ?>
```

Acredito que a variável Iterativa (neste caso `$i`) tenha que ser utilizada pra identificar qual linha está sendo impressa

Answer (score -1):

Penso que o erro esteja no LIKE. 
Tente substituir 
"SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE funcionario LIKE '%$parametro%' ORDER BY id_matricula" 
por 
"SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE funcionario='%$parametro%' ORDER BY id_matricula"

Comment: D4rck G4m3r o like seria para trazer os resultados que contenham o parâmetro, tente não responder caso não tenha certeza. De uma olhada: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Desculpe se estou a tentar ajudar e se nunca vi um SELECT com LIKE e apenas com =. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html